# How to do a ManyToMany relationship, with hibernate, in Java-EE?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish-5

I keep getting this error when building my maven project with dependencies:

```
Exception Description: The target entity of the relationship attribute 
[template] on the class [class pt.ipleiria.dae.entities.Configuration] 
cannot be determined.  When not using generics, ensure the target entity is 
defined on the relationship mapping.
```

I have these 2 entities with the following code:
Configuration:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="configurations")
private Template template;
private String name;
private ConfigurationState state;
private String version;
private String description;
private List<Module> modules;
private List<Resource> resources;
private List<String> parameters;
private List<String> extensions;
private String contrato;
```

Template(Owner of the relationship):

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="TEMPLATE_CONFIGURATIONS",
joinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
inverseJoinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
)
private List<Configuration> configurations;
```

I want to have a many to many relationship since a "Templates" holds several "Configurations", and "Configurations" can be in several "Templates"(of configurations).

Comment: 1) can you please show the whole java code of Template and Configuration. 2) the @JoinTable mapping is wrong you cannot have two columns with the same name

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have a BaseEntity which is a MappedSuperClass that has an id field with the "@GeneratedValue" tag.
The rest of the code is contructor with getters and setters.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira: In Configuration Entity it should be a list-  like this `List<Template> templates`.

Comment: @Richa the data structure would be Template [ Configuration, Configuration2...]
why would it be a list of Templates?

Comment: @RicardoFerreira: Since there is many to Many relation ship between Template and Configuration meaning Template can have multiple Configurations and a configuration can have multiple templates. In case a configuration can have only one template, you need to specify `OneToMany` relationship  in `Template` Entity and `ManyToOne` relationship in `Configuration` entity.

Comment: @Richa that was it, thank you. If you'd like, post it as an answer so I accept.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira: Did that solve your problem.

Comment: @Richa It did, because I was going for the wrong relationship. Didn't quite understand how it works, now that you've mentioned, I've searched a bit and understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the exception you defined comes when you do not define `Generics` while defining `Many` side of the relationship like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810463/when-not-using-generics-ensure-the-target-entity-is-defined-on-the-relationship)

Though in your case, there is some other issue.

Since you have applied `@ManyToMany` relationship between `Configuration` and `Template` , it should be defined like this in Configuration Entity.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="configurations")
 private List<Template> templates;
```

In case you have a requirement that Configuration can have only on template while a template can have multiple Configurations, you should go with `OneToMany` relationship. In Configuration Entity you will have:

```
@ManyToOne(mappedBy="configurations")
private Template template;
```

And in Template Entity, you will have

```
@OneToMany
private List<Configuration> configurations;
```

Hope This Helps!!